# Importing packages from another drive in java?

Tags: java, package

I have a package named `q` in my d: drive and another package name `p` which is in my c: drive.

How can i import my p package in q package?

Comment: google java classpath

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `classpath` to include all locations where your `packages` are located.